# Input box that displays the sum of the values of two other inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am working on a project, and I need to calculate the total of values of two input boxes, and display the total in a third box.

```
<p>Membership: <input type='text' name='paid' /></p>
<p>+Donation: <input type='text' name='donation' /></p>
<p>=Total Paid: <input type='text' name='total' /></p>
```

I think this can be done with jQuery or Javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: to avoid downvotes and a question ban, consider changing your title to be more descriptive. for some good examples, see this post http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:-

Javascript

```
function getTotal() {
        var paid = document.getElementsByName('paid')[0].value;
        var donation = document.getElementsByName('donation')[0].value;
        var total = (+paid) + (+donation);
        document.getElementsByName('total')[0].value = total;
    }
```

HTML

```
<p>Membership: <input type='text' name='paid' /></p>
<p>+Donation: <input type='text' name='donation' onblur="getTotal()"/></p>
<p>=Total Paid: <input type='text' name='total' /></p>
```

You can call this function to get total.

Comment: please include example with `onkeyup` or `onblur`. excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery `.val()` method to get the values of the source `input` elements which will be strings. To parse the strings to numbers prepend each with a `+` which is equivalent to `.parseInt( ... )`.

```
$('input[name=total]').val( +$('input[name=paid]').val() + +$('input[name=donation]').val() );
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/KY23R/1/)

Now you can wrap the above code within a function or an event handler to suit your needs.

Comment: answer needs to provide at least a brief description as well to fit policy guidelines

Comment: Sure, just did. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can use on blur binding for dynamic result. so whenever any field is change result value is updated accordingly.

```
$('input').blur(function(){
     $('input[name=total]').val( +$('input[name=paid]').val() + $('input[name=donation]').val() );
 });
```

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jdK4b/1/)

Comment: You could combine, blur keyup, and keydown and onchange to cover all of the edge cases. perhaps wrapping the actual calculation in its own function, then calling it from each event block.